# using the same XSLT style sheet for huge number of XML files

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xslt

I wanna use a same XSLT style sheet for all of the XML files in a directory and write all of the result in just one XML file. Also I want to add some elements to the output file, which the value of elements is not provided by those XML files (the values are provided from a text file) which means I have a mixture of XSLT,FileSTREAM,LINQ IN C#. I need some help to start, I don't know that can I mix all of them?

Comment: Can you show us some code? What have you tried to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to look at the collection() function in XSLT 2.0 (on .NET you can use Saxon or XMLPrime if you need XSLT 2.0 support). This allows you to process all the files in a directory from within a single stylesheet, merging them into a single output file or into multiple output files. You can also use unparsed-text() to read non-XML files, and xsl:analyse-string to parse them; and you can call out to extension functions written in C# if you really need to.